# Powershell. How to change a key for a web.config xml file for all folders in directory?

Tags: xml, powershell, directory, web-config, appsettings

How do I make it change for all web.config files in C:\Script? Not just one of them specifically but all of them in the directory. Thanks!

```
   $webConfig = 'C:\Script\web.config'
    $doc = (gc $webConfig) -as [xml]
    $doc.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings/add[@key="EMAIL_FROM"]/@value').'#text' = 'email@gmailcom'
    $doc.Save($webConfig)
```

Comment: You can use `Get-ChildItem` to get all the *.config files then you just need a `foreach` loop.

Comment: can you give me an example for this problem?

Comment: can someone else who wants to help help with this? much appreciated

Comment: All you need is in the PS help files and `Santiago Squarzon` response is correct and review the examples, would give you the answer. This is a very common thing to do. What did you search for? ['Powershell parse xml'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Powershell+parse+xml%27&t=h_&ia=web) XML/JSON are core to PowerShell. There are specific built-in cmdlets for that use case. Secondly, XML is just text, like regular text, you can use the Select-String cmdlet with -Replece to globally modify a file. This a common question with tons of examples all over the web, on Youtube, and right here on SO.

Comment: Just an FYI; when getting code from wherever follow these rules: `1`. Never, ever run anyone's code if you do not understand what it is doing, or be willing to fully accept the outcomes. No matter where or whom; unless you are will to accept all consequences of running it.
`2.` Never, ever run destructive code (new/add/create/update, move/remove/delete/update/modify, etc.), without fully checking results before you do. Master the use of WhatIf/Confirm/Trace-Command/Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer.
`3`. All input is evil, no matter where it comes from until you validate it first, before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. All the below is info garnered from the help info.

Using .Net namespaces in PowerShell for your use case is more commonly done like this...

```
[xml]$webConfig = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Script\web.config'
```

... but hey, choices, right. It is also best to just use the built-In PowerShell cmdlets for XML.

```
Get-Command -Name '*xml*' 
# Results
<#
CommandType Name          Version Source                      
----------- ----          ------- ------                      
Cmdlet      ConvertTo-Xml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Export-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Import-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Select-Xml    3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Select-Xml).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Select-Xml).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Examples
# Results
<#
 $Path = "$Pshome\Types.ps1xml"
 $XPath = "/Types/Type/Members/AliasProperty"
 Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
 [xml]$Types = Get-Content $Pshome\Types.ps1xml
 Select-Xml -Xml $Types -XPath "//MethodName"
 $Namespace = @{command = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10"; maml = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10"; dev = 
 $Path = "$Pshome\en-us\*dll-Help.xml"
 $Xml = Select-Xml -Path $Path -Namespace $Namespace -XPath "//command:name"
 $Xml | Format-Table @{Label="Name"; Expression= {($_.node.innerxml).trim()}}, Path -AutoSize
 $Xml = @"
 Select-Xml -Content $Xml -XPath "//edition" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
 $Xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//edition" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
 $SnippetNamespace = @{snip = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Snippets"}
 Select-Xml -Path $Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Snippets -Namespace $SnippetNamespace -XPath "//snip:Title" | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml}
#>
Get-Help -Name Select-Xml -Detailed
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Full
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Online
```

Though one can use Select-String as well.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Select-String).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Select-String).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Select-String -Examples
Get-Help -Name Select-String -Detailed
Get-help -Name Select-String -Full
Get-help -Name Select-String -Online
```

Here is an SO Q&A regarding a similar use case that I provided the accepted answer for.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008189/powershell-find-and-update-all-instances-of-named-object-property-recursively/67009139#67009139
```

Though the OP's use case is a JSON file, the same approach can be used for XML, though using the PowerShell XML cmdlets is more prudent.

```
 Select-Xml -xpath '//data/value[contains(.,"the the")]' | 
ForEach-Object{$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Again, many examples like this all over the web:

> [PowerShell 'recursive replace select-xml'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell%20%27recursive%20replace%20select-xml%27&t=h_&ia=web)

As for this...

> "all web.config files in C:\Script? Not just one of them "

...getting all files in a folder path/tree, the is what...

> Get-ChildItem

... cmdlet is for, along with using iteration via a loop. A common/necessary daily this to do for any 1:Many thing.

> [PowerShell 'for loop'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell%20%27for%20loop%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Which is what `@Santiago Squarzon` was telling you.

So, just modifying your code post to just this.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'RootPathToConfigFiles' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $webConfig = $PSItem.FullName
    $doc = (Get-Content -Path $webConfig) -as [xml]
    $doc.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings/add[@key="EMAIL_FROM"]/@value').'#text' = 'email@gmailcom'
    $doc.Save($webConfig)
}
```